# Magento2 No Payment methods showing in Frontend

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout

I am developing a site on a local server using developer mode (in `env.php`) I enable the checkout to the payment page, however, despite setting up all payment methods (individually as well to test for any conflicts) it is showing as **No Payment Methods**

I have Enabled all Methods.

Can anyone shed any light?

Comment: have you enable payment method from backend (Admin) ?

Comment: I have gone to Stores>Configuration> Checkout section selected all the payment gateways and enabled them. Is there anywhere else?

Comment: check Payment from Applicable Countries and Payment from Specific Countries  Settings for payment as well

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am having the same problem. Klarna is not showing as a payment option on checkout.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/151888)

Answer (score 22):

Have you override the file checkout_index_index.xml ? 
If, yes, make sure you have created your custom checkout_index_index.xml in the right folder like : `design/frontend/NameSpace/your_theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/override/base/checkout_index_index.xml`

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html

Hope it help

Comment: Worked perfectly +1

Comment: This mush be the accepted answer :-) Saved a day

Comment: working like wow.. :) +1

Answer (score 0):

Clear your cache and maybe upgrade and compile your code.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Navigate to your Magento folder in your Terminal and run commands if your PHP versions aren't the same will see an error.

In this case you will create an alias that has the path to the MAMP PHP file

```
alias phpmamp=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.27/bin/php
```

Then run commands above with phpmamp instead of php

NOTE: alias will chance based on path and what version of php you are using

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of testing, toggle the **Enable Onepage Checkout** in **Config > Sales > Checkout** to see if the payment methods show up on the two-step checkout.

In my case, the toggle got flipped so that, although **Enable Onepage Checkout** was set to **No**, I was getting the One Page Checkout view on the frontend. After flipping the setting, I was able to see all the correct Payment Methods on the second step of the checkout process (as expected).

I'm not exactly sure "how" my checkout toggle got flipped (**yes** is now **no**) but I suspect it had something to do with PayPal config settings.

Once your Payment Methods show up then you can start troubleshooting why they don't appear on the One Page Checkout.

Answer (score -1):

Please check design/frontend/NameSpace/your_theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/override/base/checkout_index_index.xml file in theme folder or use  default checkout_index_index.xml file.