# Magento 2 Klarna payment not visible in frontend

Tags: magento2, php, payment-methods, magento2.2.6, klarna

I Have magento 2.2.6 installed with Amazon pay and ogone  payment solution, This payments works fine, but klarna payment not visible in checkout page, seems everything is fine in backend, here is screenshot [image]

Also I cant see any errors in console.

Comment: This answer might be useful for you, Please check below link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117100/magento2-no-payment-methods-showing-in-frontend

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have checked this solution, but did not work for me.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/150199)

Comment: We have this error in log                                                                                        (Bad Response: Client error: `POST https://api.playground.klarna.com/payments/v1/sessions` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:)

Comment: Did you resolve this problem? I'm getting the same error

Comment: Did you resolve this problem => Client error: POST https://api.playground.klarna.com/payments/v1/sessions? I'm getting the same error

Comment: I am also getting 403 forbidden error with M2.4.1, any resolution for this?