# paypal not showing

Tags: magento2, php, paypal

I have a Magento 2 site with little to no customization on it.  For some reason PayPal no longer shows up as a payment method even though it is properly configured in the admin configuration area.  All customizations that were added (paid theme, custome shipping module, cybersource) have been disabled, and Paypal still doesn't work/show up in the checkout.  Has anyone else run into this issue?

I don't really have any code to share as beside the custom items mentioned above, the site is as it should be for version 2.3.0.

Comment: Just some ideas: Could be many reasons... Is the order amount reasonable? Is the currency supported by paypal? Other ideas here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117100/magento2-no-payment-methods-showing-in-frontend